# How can i find a file by part of its name? C#

Tags: c#

Currently using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` when looking for files in a certain directory, I need all files that contain the word 'access' in the file name. I know you can filter by the starting character or the end character or by partial name as seen below:

```
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, partialName , SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
    readFile(currentFile);
}
```

However as the file names are like the following: `3492_access_log_76`, it doesn't pick up access as technically the partial file name is: `3492_access_log_76`.

Is there a way of taking even a sequence of letters, such as 'acc'?

Comment: You really should try to read the documentation of the methods that you use.

Answer (score 2):

Use wildcards.  `"*access*"` will get every file that contains the word "access".

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter is a search pattern. You should use wildcard characters to build the pattern you want. E.g. if your partial name can appear anyway in the file name you should add `*` characters before and after the partial name:

```
var partialName = "*access*"; // or "*acc*" if you want less precise search
```

`*` means any number of any characters